# Hover opacity transition on child

Tags: css, hover, transition

I am trying to make the appearance of the child element transition opacity when the parent is hovered. Can someone please explain to me why this doesn't work, I'm sure this is a duplicate question but I can't seem to adapt any similar questions to resolve my issue, please forgive my dumbness.

http://jsfiddle.net/vg0hLstr/1/

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='#'>hover me</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h1>Tell me why</h1>
                    <h2>the nested ul opacity doesn't transition</h2>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

&

```
nav ul {
    position:relative;
    width:64px;
    margin:350px 0 0 0; /*for the fiddle*/
    padding:0;
    background:#999;
    list-style:none;
}

nav img {float:left width:64px; height:64px;}
nav a {float:left;}

nav ul li {float:left; background-color:#999;}

nav ul li:hover > ul {display:block; opacity:1;}

nav ul ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0.5;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    bottom:100%;
    transition:opacity 1s linear;
}
```

I have made and used the above menu(without the transition) for just standard pop-out menus but i would like to transition it's opacity, I have seen some sites do it, but I get super confused going through other peoples code. I'm relatively new & self-taught to HTML/CSS so a little walk-through of what i'm doing wrong would be most helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Need little clarity, where do you hover and which particular elements opacity should be set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps this is what you want: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/vg0hLstr/2/)

first, your animation didn't work because you use style `display: none`, which didn't render the `element` and didn't reserve space for it, so it won't get the animation effect of the `opacity`, so if you want to use the `opacity` transation, you need to use `visibility: hidden` because even though your `element` is hidden, it's still there. So what you need is just change your `CSS` to this

```
nav ul li:hover > ul {visibility:visible; opacity:1;}

nav ul ul {
    visibility:hidden;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    bottom:100%;
    transition:opacity 1s linear, visibility 1s linear;
}
```

note that you need also need to add transation for the `visibility`, or else, it will just pop in and out when you hover over it, and also `visibility: hidden` will work because your element is using `position: absolute`, if not, it will leave a space between the previous and next `element`

Comment: Thanks so much, worked like a charm. And i understand it better!